# mysql simple master-slave replication stops without any errors

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21-20 (it's Percona fork, if it's matter).
Trying to make simple M-S replication, only 2 servers, different id-s.
Replications starts normally, but after a while (several hours usually) slave stops to execute any operations, recieved from master. I mean in SHOW SLAVE STATUS

```
lave_IO_Running: Yes
  Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

and Master_Log_File and ead_Master_Log_Pos contiunue to grow (and Relay_Log_Space too), but Exec_Master_Log_Pos just stops at one position. No any errors in logs,  Last_Errno: 0, restart of mysqld and start/stop slave don't resolve situation.

So, i try change slave server to another, with different OS (debian-9, like on master) - the same results.

The replication-related config options are pretty simple, the same on master and slave, except, of course, server-id and auto_increment_offset.

```
server-id = 2
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log-bin-index = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.index
max_binlog_size = 512M
expire_logs_days = 7
binlog-checksum         = crc32
binlog-format           = MIXED
relay-log=mj747-relay-bin
auto_increment_offset = 2
auto_increment_increment = 2
```

So, any ideas, where should i look ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are queries actually being made? If there is nothing to write from the master than it won’t work.

If there was any problem such as network issue etc. Then the slave would stop itself.

Comment: >Are queries actually being made?
yes, master's load is peretty nice. and if nothing to write, it seems to me that Seconds Behind Master would be 0 ? 

No problem with network. and i think, that network problems gone away after stop/start slave.